# Storing the csv file using a variable using TCOM

Tags: file, tcl

I want to save the csv file using the value of the variable in TCOM.

Here is how i save it using a hard coded value test1.csv, which works fine.

```
   $workbook SaveAs {c:\test\test1.csv} $XlFileFormat(xlCSV)
```

But when i want to save it with the value of a variable which is similar to

```
    $workbook SaveAs {c:\test\$testname.csv} $XlFileFormat(xlCSV)
```

I get error or i just get the file named $testname.csv, but not the value of the variable. How to do this.? I even tried ${testname}, this doesnt work.

Comment: search [stackoverflow for 0x800A03EC](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=0x800A03EC), lots of questions and answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclosing somethnig in [braces](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) means nearly no substitutions are performed. Remove the braces and do something like `$workbook SaveAs "C:/test/$testname.csv" $XlFileFormat(xlCSV)`

Comment: tried this, still getting  0x800a03ec {The file could not be accessed} error.

Comment: Is the file currently being used by another process?

Comment: No it is not. But it just works fine if u explicitly give some value to the file name.

Comment: OK, this is as simple as dirt: what if you do `set x "C:/test/$testname.csv"; puts $x; $workbook SaveAs $x $XlFileFormat(xlCSV)` -- does the printout produced by `puts` look correct?

Comment: I'd be _strongly_ tempted to force the use of backslashes when passing a filename to Excel this way. However, [`file nativename`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M24) will do exactly the conversion required, so you don't have to do much fussing around. You would apply it to create the argument to `SaveAs`.

Comment: Also, if you say this in two places in your code, refactor it into a little procedure. Make it easy to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$workbook SaveAs "c:\test\${testname.csv}" $XlFileFormat(xlCSV)
```

Comment: `$workbook SaveAs "c:/test/${testname}.csv" $XlFileFormat(xlCSV)` looks more sensibly--I doubt anyone would have a variable named "testname.csv" in their code ;-)  And yes, as @thelazydeveloper pointer out, one has to use forward slashes in a double-quoted string, or quote backslashes (`"C:\\foo\\bar"`).

Comment: Hehe, I guess I'm a lazy developer too! Thanks for pointing it out.